# Trying to create an app on RPI to communicate 2 ways with server/website

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I could use some advice for this project (beginner here).

**Situation:**

We have 10 or so families who need reminders to take medicine, appointments reminders etc.

We would like to find a way to have these families update their medicine intake/medical needs, twice-3-times daily using a simple touchscreen button app.]

**Scenario:**

Family one receives Raspberry Pi with app preloaded initially. Enters patients information in home (names address etc.)

We receive that info on a website/webserver, we can visualize it on a map, we automatically push reminders to take medicine, alerts, updates.

Family received updated, reminders etc.

(We are planning to use Raspberry Pi with wifi-bluetooth and to add a GRSM card for cell service in case no internet is available)

We also so we can add on a cam, is there a way to be able to see patients remotely if they ask for that thru the app?( welfare check)
is this feasible with Raspberry Pi?

We purchased some Raspberry Pi zero w and Raspberry Pi 3.

Thank you for any basic simple guidance. We are trying to learn to code.

Comment: This appears to be a software design problem rather than an RPi specific issue.  You'd probably be better asking this question over on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: The question is to broad.

Comment: While this could certainly be done with something besides a Raspberry Pi, I think there are enough potential RPi-specific features that could be used to make it appropriate for this forum. The GPIO interface is well suited for simple pushbuttons, the camera interface makes incorporation of video straightforward, and the on-board display interface makes a self-contained unit relatively easy to build. Let's not be overly-zealous in chasing people with legitimate queries that could be well served by the RPi away. The RPi may not be the only answer, but it can be a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a webserver, send data from Python to PHP to then put into MySQL. Once you have the data in a MySQL server you can do a lot with it. Graph it, sort, count,

This is a basic example but it should give you and idea.

eg send data to php

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def SendUpdate(
 userdata = {"first_name": first_name, "last_name" : last_name, "pills" : pills}
 resp = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/insert_into_database.php', params=userdata)

#button press GPIO23
while True:
 if GPIO.input(23):
  SendUpdate
 else:
  print "Red pill or the Blue pill?"

time.sleep(0.1)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

PHP into MySQL, insert_into_database.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "password");

$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['last_name']);
$pills = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['pills']);

// insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO patients (first_name, last_name, pills) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$pills')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Success.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR";
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Then if you want a user to check for reminders you could run a Python script as a cron job that opens up a Python script the loads a php script that checks the database for reminders.

```
#crontab -e
#this will run every 5 mins
*/5 * * * * /home/pi/checkForReminders.py
```

Answer (score 0):

One huge hurdle you need to address is compliance with HIPAA requirements, at least if you're in the US. Those requirements are  part of why simple healthcare services cost so much. Assuming you get through those hurdles...

For the day-to-day pushing of reminders and patient responses, look into using an Internet-based MQTT broker. It is well suited to this sort of usage, and works behind a variety of firewalls without any complicated setup on the patient end. It would also work well with any physical buttons you add onto the device with minimal complications.

So far as the patient registering the device, it could be as simple as an identifier applied to the device case that the patient enters into an enrollment web site.  That could be linked to the identifier used for MQTT (see above) that is used to "talk" to the device. If you provide a cell modem and service, it might be simple enough for an elderly patient to call a number and enter the information via phone. Otherwise, you do have to deal with walking them through setting up their wifi. A small display on the RPi would be useful for this.

A lot of what you are asking is open-ended, but there are answers that take advantage of the RPi that are worth discussing to help you focus your questions.

Good luck with this. It sounds like the sort of worthy cause that we should strive to encourage supporting here.